# Set up one instance of ChromeDriver for Panther, rather than creating one for each request

Tags: php, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, symfony-panther

I am using Symfony Panther for web scraping (not testing) in a PHP project that does not use Symfony. I installed via Composer. Each time I need to scrape a link submitted by a user, I start a new Chrome Browser.

```
$client = Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient('/usr/bin/chromedriver');
$client->request('GET', $url);
$crawler = $client->waitFor('body');
```

Starting a new Chrome browser for each submitted `$url` is slow and resource intensive, so I want to keep the Chrome Client running on port 9515 and then each user's `$url` request can connect to that one same instance. Based on [some](https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/184) user [comments](https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/187) on Github, it sounds like a reasonable method:

- Spin up a Chrome instance on the Linux server, running on port 9515
- Make each url request connect to that instance.

I placed the first line i.e. with createChromeClient in a php script for a CRON job, but it never starts up the chrome client, and I get no errors either. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there progress? 10x

Comment: I'd like to know, too.

Answer (score 0):

"Not showing" the browser (Chrome here) is the default way, as it is faster. It is called "headless"

To show it, you have to specify "PANTHER_NO_HEADLESS" :

```
PANTHER_NO_HEADLESS=1 vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml
```

also, you could check if chome is running with : (or any system log)

```
ps aux | grep chrome
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Where would I set up this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

@Cogicero
You set this option in phpunit.xml.dist file :

```
<env name="PANTHER_NO_HEADLESS" value="1" />
```

And comment it if u don't want to see the browser.